# My XPath to locate input fields on dialog box, is not working in script?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, dialog

My application dialogue box has few input fields which I am able to locate in the browser using XPath, but the script gives an error:

`NO SUCH ELEMENT exception`

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl39$g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886$ctl00$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl39_g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Maximum Attendees Required Field" class="ms-input" size="11" style="ime-mode:inactive;">
```

XPath I am using:

```
//input[@id='ctl00_ctl39_g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField']
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: <input name="ctl00$ctl39$g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886$ctl00$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl39_g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Maximum Attendees Required Field" class="ms-input" size="11" style="ime-mode:inactive;">

Comment: Please add more context to your question, what programming language or the link to webpage and point to where the `HTML` element is?

Comment: I am using selenium java, the HTML element is present on a dialog/popup box for which I am able to locate the title, but unable to locate the elements in one of the frame

Comment: Also, do tell `webpage` link.

Comment: <span dir="none">
  <input name="ctl00$ctl39$g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886$ctl00$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl39_g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Maximum Attendees Required Field" class="ms-input" size="11" style="ime-mode:inactive;" /><br />
 </span>

Comment: Maybe try waiting for some time after opening page using `selenium`. Also, include your script in the question for more help and webpage link.

Comment: https://ctssp-test-auth.caseytechschool.vic.edu.au/Lists/ScheduleProgram/calendar.aspx?source=https://ctssp-test-auth.caseytechschool.vic.edu.au/Pages/schedulepicker.aspx&program=24

Comment: actionLib.Click(adminSetupObjectrepository.addLink, "Add Link");
     if(actionLib.IsElementVisible(adminSetupObjectrepository.dialogTitle))
     {
      actionLib.Click(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_ctl39_g_1447640c_4de8_44db_9142_3f8ebf91a886_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField']"),"Date Selection");    
}

Comment: This is my code and it fails in last line after finding dialog title

Comment: 1. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917686/my-xpath-to-locate-input-fields-on-dialog-box-is-not-working-in-script#) your question and add all new information there instead of in the comments.
2. Check if the element you are looking for is under frame/iframe element. In that case, you can find it with your browser but need to first switch to that frame/ifrmae to find it in selenium.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I think iFrame is causing the problem. But the HTML was little complicated with iFrame within Dialog box to switch to the frame. I have found a work around by opening the dialog box as new URL in separate window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will scan the page for the item.
`"//input[@type='text']"`

Respectively if there is more than one input on the page you can do:
`"//input[@type='text'][1]"` 
`"(//input[@type='text'])[2]"`